# How to delete table records on cascade without the program freezing?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jframe

this is my delete button method, it takes the college name as a primary key and deletes it so the whole record gets deleted. However, it can't be deleted because this table COLLEGE is the parent table for the STUDENTS table and DEPARTMENT table. I want to delete on cascade but the button freezes when I click it but if I drop the foreign keys it works pretty well. To sum up, I want to delete the record on cascade without having any trouble in the JFrame.

College table

[image]

```
private void deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{
    String sql = " DELETE FROM college where college_name = ?";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","moe");
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1,college_name.getText());         
    pst.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deleted successfully");
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex); 
   }
   showData(); 
}
```

Comment: Don't do blocking operations like database access on the UI event thread. Use something like `SwingWorker` to offload it to a separate thread. However, the actually diagnose the problem, we need a [mre].

Comment: To expand of what Mark Rotteveel commented, I would say to never do non-GUI operations on the UI event thread. Assume all background processes will block the UI; giving the appearance that the GUI has "frozen". Since this is for Java Swing application, I recommend reading this from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: thank you thank you thank youuuu so much guys u saved my day